The Enter key works every time I call addEventListener ("click")
I'm trying to make a calculator, and in the middle of the coding, I see that when I press the enter key, he calls the last addEventListener ("click") I used, but I don't set any work for the enter key. How can I fix?
That's my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/calculator.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Reddit+Mono:wght@200..900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Calculadora em JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="resultado">
            <p class="resultado_anterior"></p>
            <p class="resultado_calc"></p>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="porcentagem input_logico">%</a>
        <a href="" class="reset_teclado">CE</a>
        <a href="" class="reset_calc">C</a>
        <a href="" class="backspace">&#9003;</a>
        <a href="" class="um_dividido">1/x</a>
        <a href="" class="quadrado">Potência (2)</a>
        <a href="" class="raiz">Raiz (2)</a>
        <a href="" class="divisao input_logico">÷</a>
        <a href="" class="sete input">7</a>
        <a href="" class="oito input">8</a>
        <a href="" class="nove input">9</a>
        <a href="" class="multiplicacao input_logico">×</a>
        <a href="" class="quatro input">4</a>
        <a href="" class="cinco input">5</a>
        <a href="" class="seis input">6</a>
        <a href="" class="menos input_logico">-</a>
        <a href="" class="um input">1</a>
        <a href="" class="dois input">2</a>
        <a href="" class="tres input">3</a>
        <a href="" class="mais input_logico">+</a>
        <a href="" class="negativo_positivo">+/-</a>
        <a href="" class="zero input">0</a>
        <a href="" class="virgula input">,</a>
        <a href="" class="igual">=</a>
    </section>
    <script src="../js/calculator.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

And my JS code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    inputs();
    reset()
    backspace()
    negativo_positivo()
})

const RESULTADO = document.querySelector(".resultado_calc")
const RESULTADO_ANTERIOR = document.querySelector(".resultado_anterior")
let aux = ""
let currentInput = ""
let prevInput = ""

// Making the keys work

function inputs() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".input").forEach(input => {
        window.addEventListener("keypress", tecla => {
            if (tecla.key === input.innerHTML) {
                currentInput = RESULTADO.textContent += `${tecla.key}`
                RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
            }
        })
    })
    document.querySelectorAll(".input").forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("click", event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            currentInput += `${input.textContent}`
            RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
            
        })
    })
}

// making the backspace work

function backspace() {

    document.querySelector(".backspace").addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        currentInput = RESULTADO.textContent.slice(0, -1)
        RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
    })

    window.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
        if (event.key === "Backspace") {
            currentInput = RESULTADO.textContent.slice(0, -1)
            RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
        }
    });
}

// Turn numbers into positives or negatives

function negativo_positivo() {
    document.querySelector(".negativo_positivo").addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (RESULTADO.textContent >= 0) {
            currentInput = -(currentInput)
            return (RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput)
        } else {
            currentInput = -(currentInput)
            return (RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput)
        }
    })
}

// // addition

// window.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
//     document.querySelectorAll(".input_logico").forEach(input_logico => {
//         if (input_logico.innerHTML === event.key) {
//             event.preventDefault()
//             aux = currentInput
//             prevInput = RESULTADO_ANTERIOR.textContent = aux + input_logico.innerHTML
//             RESULTADO_ANTERIOR.textContent = prevInput
//             currentInput = ""
//             RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
//             console.log("currentInput Soma = " + currentInput)
//             console.log("prevInput Soma = " + prevInput)

//             window.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
//                 if (RESULTADO.textContent === "") {
//                     event.preventDefault()
//                     // RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
//                 } else {
//                     if (event.key === "Enter") {
//                         event.preventDefault()

//                         prevInput = RESULTADO_ANTERIOR.textContent = aux + input_logico.innerHTML + currentInput
//                         console.log(prevInput)
//                         RESULTADO_ANTERIOR.textContent = prevInput
//                         currentInput = RESULTADO.textContent = parseFloat(aux) + parseFloat(currentInput)
//                         RESULTADO.textContent = currentInput
//                         console.log("currentInput Soma2 = " + currentInput)
//                         console.log("prevInput Soma2 = " + prevInput)
//                     }
//                 }
//             })
//         }
//     })
// })

// making the reset button works

function reset() {
    document.querySelector(".reset_calc").addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        RESULTADO.textContent = ""
        RESULTADO_ANTERIOR.textContent = ""
        aux = ""
        currentInput = ""
        prevInput = ""
        console.log("reset")
    })
}


I tried to set a function to the enter key to see if it worked, but it continued to call the last event click.
And I also adde the addition function to comments. Since there was some work for the enter key, I thought it's the problem, but even the enter key still works.

If any user interface element has focus, the Enter key is treated like clicking on that element.

and its possible to remove that? i didnt put it in my css

i didnt put it in my css - what does your CSS have to do with keyboard events?

One way you could try and debug the code is by adding console.log() statements with different content into each function. That way you'll be able to see which functions are being called when the enter key is pressed. From there, you can see where the logic of your if statements might not be acting like you were expecting.

You could unfocus them when you click on them (event.target.blur()) or refocus your input after a click (input.focus()). You could perhaps also use tabIndex="-1" to remove them from the focus flow entirely, though that has accessibility concerns. You could also event.preventDefault() on document.onkeydown when it's an Enter keypress and respond there so you can never use the Enter key for any other purpose. A plethora of solutions.

the event.target.blur() its worked, thank you
